# The requested resource / was not found on this server PHP

Tags: php, server, localhost

I ran the php server on cmd using `php -S localhost:8080`, like this:

[image]

And I got this problem opening the localhost:

[image]

What do I supposed to do?

Comment: is there a index.php or index.html file in that folder?

Comment: Make sure your router name and directory name in public folder are not same? I faced this issue today and changed the directory name to fix this issue. It worked. Thanks to ask this question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was missing `index.php` in the *root folder*.

Answer (score 8):

This error also occurs when you have a path with the same name as a directory in the public folder:

**Definition of path in the file routes.php**

```
    Route::get('Glaciares',function(){
        return view('Principal.Glaciares.Acerca');
    });
```

**Public folder**

[image]

Comment: This post just function in Laravel

Comment: Fuqqqqqqqq, **same name as a directory in the public folder**!!

Classic autosabotage ;(

Ty dude @Robert LUgo

Comment: This is perfect answer

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem which occurred by running the `php -S localhost:8002` in the wrong directory.

`Project/src/` -> caused the error

`Project/src/public` -> Solved

Comment: Run the command that starts the dev server in the directory that has the index.php file.

Comment: Hi I want to run 'php -S localhost:8002' to accept `stdin` request. I mean run standalone php sever and put the code to run from the command line without need to directory or files ?

Answer (score 1):

[error resolved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EqAu.png)

I personally solved this error by putting my file name after
http://0.0.0.0:3000/hello.php like this, you can see the results in the image above

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I named the file `lesson.php` and had the same problem, but changing it to `index.php` solved it! also as @prince mentioned adding the file name like this `http://localhost:8080/filname.php` will solve it.

according to the manual in php.net

> If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the document root has been reached. If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned.

[read more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding filename after url, if you don't want to do this everytime, you can just specify the entrypoint to the application is your setting.json.

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
        "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
        "-S",
        "localhost:0"
    ],
    "program": "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_THE_PHP_FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_SERVE",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "port": 9003,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
        "action": "openExternally"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run that command in the folder/directory your site is in and you have to have a file names index.html

Answer (score -1):

in rails, Missing

```
def index

end
```

in your controller.

if not, restart your computer and everything is fine

Comment: The built in php server doesn’t support rails.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give the folder path after `localhost:4000` as follows;

`http://localhost:4000/folderName/index.php`

If you made a special directory for PHP files or you can directly use root folder as the path